# How to query a MongoDB database

Tags: mongodb

I am starting with Mongo DB and I am trying to query my database for a year for example 2021 and I do not know how to do this is the start of my request

db.getCollection('Mission').count()

Comment: I suggest starting with MongoDB documentation (they have lots of it, including lots of getting-started docs), and then posting a specific question here, with all required details.

Comment: Can you provide same sample data (as formatted text please)?